# Mocking Generic types using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, jersey, mockito

I am writing a test case using JUnit and Mockito for the REST services using jersey. I am getting a null object instead of a mocked object for the Response class.

Code under test

```
Response response = builder
                        .put( Entity.entity( new ByteArrayInputStream( jsonObj.toString().getBytes() ), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ), Response.class );
```

Test case:

```
private Invocation.Builder builder; 
private Entity<ByteArrayInputStream> inputStream;
private Response response;
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    builder = mock( Invocation.Builder.class );
    inputStream = (Entity<ByteArrayInputStream>)mock( Entity.class );
    response = mock( Response.class );
}

@Test
public void myTest() {
when( builder.put( inputStream, Response.class ) ).thenReturn( response );
}
```

So this line of code gives me a null response. Is there any other way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved this issue so I thought to share it what I actually did. 
`Mockito.when(builder.put(any(Entity.class), any(Class.class))).thenReturn(response);`

above statement gives me the mocked Response. Now I can do anything I want with the mocked Response object. I can mock the getStatus method and return a status code or anything else.

Hope this help those who Mockito and PowerMockito Api.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are mixing up various things.

Your production code does:

```
Entity.entity( new ByteArrayInputStream( ...
```

So, what you got there is:

- a **static** call (`Entity.entity()`)
- a call to `new`

Both of these operations **can not** be mocked with Mockito. It is as simple as that.

In order to mock **static** method calls, you have to look into frameworks such as PowerMock(ito) or JMockit.

But I rather recommend a different solution: consider reworking your production code. Instead making static+new call; create something like

```
interface EntityProvider {
  public Entity of(bytes[] data, MediaType type);
}
```

You can easily create an impl class that uses your current code - but for **testing** purposes, you can dependency-inject a mock of that interface (created via Mockito.mock()); and all of a sudden, your whole code becomes testable with Mockito again.

And no need to look into other mocking frameworks (and imho; at least PowerMockito comes with a certain amount of cost - it is not as simple as "just switch to that other framework").